# Android: Questions about AWT class equivalents for the Android library

Tags: java, android, graphics, awt

I know that there's no way to include AWT classes directly into my Android program, but I thought I'd ask about what classes are equivalent. I know that the `Bitmap` class is equivalent to `BufferedImage`, but I also need `SampleModel`, `DataBufferByte`, `WritableRaster` and `IndexColorModel`. What are the equivalent classes for those?

I'm using these classes to parse DICOM files to show the images as a video.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You won't find equivalent classes, maybe classes of similar function. A better strategy would be to learn how Android UI operates and expand your knowledge of UI frameworks.  Learn what Android does best and adapt your library for it.

Comment: I'm actually porting over an existing Java app, so I wanted to re-write as little of it as possible. Thanks anyways.